# What are the internal macros of a star environment?

Tags: macros, environments

What are for example the star versions of the internal macros `\flalign` and `\endflalign` ?

Comment: There is no general rule, and by far not all macros have a starred variant. These are technically distinct macros. Even worse, a star can change its meaning/effect depending on the document it is used in, try e.g. a `figure*` environment in a one or two column environment.

Comment: IIRC, the only difference between \flalign and \begin{flalign} (for example) is an additional group layer.

Comment: @JohnKormylo ams alignments grab their whole body so need to look ahead for an explicit `\end{...}` so you can not use the `\foo...\endfoo` form, you have o use an environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question isn't that clear but the definitions of `flalign` and `flalign*` are

```
\newenvironment{flalign}{%
  \start@align\tw@\st@rredfalse\m@ne
}{%
  \endalign
}
\newenvironment{flalign*}{%
  \start@align\tw@\st@rredtrue\m@ne
}{%
  \endalign
}
```

So they are the same except that `\ifst@rred` is true in the star form (and mostly they are the same as `align`).

That switch is tested at various points in the code for `(fl)align(*)` typically with lines like

```
 \ifst@rred\else\global\@eqnswtrue\fi
```

---

If you mean what is the macro that holds the top level definition, in the way that `\flalign` holds the definition of `\begin{flalign}` then that is `\flalign*`  but you can only type it that way if you do `` \catcode\`\*=11 `` to make `*` a letter so normally it would be accessed via

```
\csname flalign*\endcsname
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why do I forget to use csname ? A big mystery... :-)